# How do I extract everything but the URL protocol (https://) using REGEXEXTRACT?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to find a regex formula that takes this URL

https://info.example.edu/programs/degree/page1/

and turns it into this

info.example.edu/programs/degree/page1/

I currently have this formula but it neglects the subdomain

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\..+)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this instead.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[^/]+//(.+)")
```

This captures anything after `//`

#### Output:

[image: output]